# Shaving off space on an Ubuntu 20.04 ova file?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm building an Open Virtual Appliance file for a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1. I'm using VirtualBox 6.1.12 r139181. I want to be able to share the ova file with students that I teach. My problem is that the ova file is 4.1GB, and so too big to fit on a USB formatted with FAT32.

I'm looking for ways to shave off some space from the ova file. Here's what I've tried:
VBoxManage modifymedium --compact Ubuntu20-04-disk001.vdi
which had no effect (the VDI file is 11GB).

I then removed as much unnecessary software as I could from the Ubuntu virtual machine, including LibreOffice Calc, Draw and Impress.

I also ran apt clean, apt autoremove and autoclean.

Finally I installed localepurge and removed all unnecessary locales.

The only software I've added is Terminator, Spyder and Thonny, and I need those.

Can anyone please suggest a way to reduce the size of the VDI/OVA?

Thanks and regards
Cormac

Comment: When you originally created the container for the VM, did you set it to a variable sized or a fixed size?  If it's a fixed size, it doesn't matter how much you remove from inside the container, the container will still take up the same size on the disk. I suggest you set up a new VM container that uses a variable size on the disk

Comment: Hi Nmath. Thanks for responding. I set up the disk as Dynamically allocated storage, with a virtual size of 25GB, actual size 11GB, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Hmmm.. can you determine the sum of all of the data and software? 4GB is pretty small.  Can you use a different file system instead of FAT?

Comment: Hi Nmath. I can use other formats (e.g. exFAT), but the problem is the students that I want to share the file with. They'll typically have FAT32-formatted USB devices. I may have to make it available via a Dropbox folder. Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: If you haven't, you could clear `/tmp` and there could be some unnecessary files in the hidden dotfiles in user folders (starting with `~/.`).